# Convert MongoDB id to date-time in Power BI

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

I have an API that includes a MongoDB ID in it, unfortunately you can't convert this ID to date-time in Mongo when using an API.

I'm trying to convert it to date-time in Power BI. I found a JavaScript function that would allow me to convert it:

```
var dateFromObjectId = function (objectId) {
    return new Date(parseInt(objectId.substring(0, 8), 16) * 1000);
};
```

In Power BI, I've managed to get the substring part of this function to work using:

```
substring = MID([objectID], 0, 8)
```

So in this case, the Mongo ID would look something like this:

```
5bec695948cbd00519d0d8ca
```

and the substring would return:

```
5bec6959
```

The next step in the JS function is to parse the string from hexadecimal to decimal so it can be converted to date time. I have not been able to find a method that works. I've tried some solutions using a custom function but they don't seem to do anything. The link below shows where I got the JS function and a conversation calculator:
https://steveridout.github.io/mongo-object-time/
If anyone can help us on this, we would appreciate it a lot.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
= #datetime(1970,1,1,0,0,0) + #duration(0,0,0,Expression.Evaluate("0x" & Text.Range([_id],0, 8)))

// [_id] is the column containing the mongo_id

// Text.Range --> Gets the first 8 characters

// Expression.Evaluate -> converts from HEX to DEC

// Adds to epoch time
```